# how to get a YAML file with vars substitution from a YAML file with {{}} variables

Tags: ansible, yaml, yq

I have a bunch of files `serverlist_xzy.yml` like this one

```yaml
    $ cat serverlist_xzy.yml
    all:
      children:
        web:
          hosts:
            srv-proxy-01:
              isWeb: true
      vars:
        zf_env: 'preprod'
        zf_zone: 'global'
        project_path:
          api: "proj_api_{{ zf_zone }}_{{ zf_env }}"
          data: "proj_data_{{ zf_zone }}_{{ zf_env }}"
          web: "proj_web_{{ zf_zone }}_{{ zf_env }}"
          flower: "proj_flower_{{ zf_zone }}_{{ zf_env }}"
        root_path:
          api: "/opt/{{ project_path['api'] }}"
          web: "/opt/{{ project_path['web'] }}"
          data: "/opt/{{ project_path['data'] }}"
        lazy_table: "{{ root_path['data'] }}/data_lazy_table"
        logrotate_logpath:
          api: "/var/log/{{ project_path['api'] }}_app"
          web: "/var/log/{{ project_path['web'] }}_app"
          worker: "/var/log/aaa_worker_{{ zf_zone }}_{{ zf_env }}_app"
          flower: "/var/log/{{ project_path['flower'] }}_app"
        htpasswd:
          path:
            api: "/etc/nginx/passwords/{{ project_path['api'] }}.passwdfile"
            web: "/etc/nginx/passwords/{{ project_path['web'] }}.passwdfile"
            flower: "/etc/nginx/passwords/{{ project_path['flower'] }}.passwfile"
    $
```

I need to grep the result of it with all vars replaced in some out.yml file

to be able to do something like this:

```bash
    $ grep worker out.yml
          worker: "/var/log/aaa_worker_global_preprod_app"
    $
```

I could do the substitution in Python but I suspect that ansible or yq
https://github.com/mikefarah/yq could do this in one line.

Comment: The data is not consistent. The dictionary *project_path* is missing the attribute *flower*.

Comment: missing flower attribute added

Answer (score 2):

The file *`serverlist_xzy.yml`* is actually an inventory file. You can use it as such. For example, the play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          srv-proxy-01:
            logrotate_logpath:
              worker: {{ hostvars['srv-proxy-01'].logrotate_logpath.worker }}
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i serverlist_xzy.yml pb.yml
  ...
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    srv-proxy-01:
      logrotate_logpath:
        worker: /var/log/aaa_worker_global_preprod_app
  ...
```

The result of the substitution is related to a particular host, *`srv-proxy-01`* in this case. The actual value of the variable *`logrotate_logpath.worker`* depends on the variables *`zf_zone`* and *`zf_env`*, which are also declared in this file. These values are subject of the [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence). Without specification of the hostname, you can take the first host from the list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          grups.all.0:
            logrotate_logpath:
              worker: {{ hostvars[groups.all.0].logrotate_logpath.worker }}
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: logrotate_logpath.worker
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i serverlist_xzy.yml pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  logrotate_logpath.worker: /var/log/aaa_worker_global_preprod_app

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```